# Pythonic to way fix circular imports in Django (with task management framework)

Tags: django, python-import, pylint, circular-dependency

I have a pattern that comes up fairly often in a Django app with some task management lib (say celery or dramatiq) that looks as follows:

```
my_app/
    executors/
        my_executor.py
    tasks/
        my_task.py
```

The circular dependency comes from the fact that the executor may schedule the task, while the task is instantiating an executor.

Executor module:

```
# my_executor.py

import my_app.tasks.my_task

class MyExecutor():
    def some_method(self):
        my_app.tasks.my_task.some_actual_task.send()
```

Task module:

```
# my_task.py

import my_app.executors.my_executor

@decorating_as_task
def some_actual_task():
    executor = my_app.executors.my_executor.MyExecutor()
    executor.execute()
```

There is no issue actually running the app (or tests), but pylint complains about a R0401: Cyclic import between the modules.

But it is not clear to me whether this type of dependency is acceptable or not (Python does not seem to be complaining) and whether there are way of actually improving the code structure (having a higher level module `my_app.task_management` importing both executors and tasks?) while pleasing pylint on this.

I have seen many similar questions but could not find a satisfactory solution from them.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, through inheritance, I isolated the circular code as follows:

```
my_app/
    abstract_executors/
        my_abstract_executor.py
    tasks/
        my_task.py
```

```
# my_abtract_executor.py

class MyAbstractExecutor():
    def some_method(self):
        self._task_to_schedule.send()

    @property
    def _task_to_schedule(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('_task_to_schedule')
```

```
# my_task.py

import my_app.abstract_executors.my_abstract_executor

@decorating_as_task
def some_actual_task():
    executor = MyExecutor()
    executor.execute()

class MyExecutor(MyAbstractExecutor):
    @property
    def _task_to_schedule(self):
        return some_actual_task
```

This avoids circular imports while allowing to define most of the execution logic in its own module. Maybe there is something better out there, but this fits the bill (avoid circular imports, please pylint, keep things isolated).